# Console displays unicode character as [], but can understand them

Tags: windows-10, console

I have a strange bug in a cmd, it displays any unicode character as .
Here what i do:

1. Run cmd.exe(font is set to Lucida Console)
2. chcp 65001
3. Paste "フォルダー" and every character displays as [], if i copy it from console and paste it somewhere else it will be again フォルダー as it must.
4. When doing cd "フォルダー" it does go to it but again displays as C:\[][][][][]\

Why it didn't display unicode characters?
**Edit:**
Actually there is no solve though...
But if you want you can use [ConEmu](http://conemu.github.io) which is improving default prompt.
In ConEmu characters are displaying *with any font*, because it *uses font that supported these chars* with selected.

Comment: Lucida Console probably doesn't have the glyphs for those Unicode values.

Comment: but there is only 2 of them "Consolas" & "Lucida Console"

Comment: <shrug> Check in charmap.

Comment: Yes, there are not any.

Comment: That is your answer then.

Comment: But earlyer in Windows 7, i used Lucida Console and it was displaying unicode characters.

Comment: I'm running Windows 7 and it also won't display the characters in your question.

Comment: Standard console does not use font linking. But ConEmu does: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10904494/1405560

Comment: Yes, i'm switching to ConEmu.